# Can someone explain and help to understand this fuzzy diagram?

Tags: machine-learning, fuzzy-logic

Could someone help me to understand in detail each step of this fuzzy diagram, because I am lost?

[image: Fuzzy]

Comment: Maybe you should explain where you took that diagram from and what your knowledge of fuzzy logic, etc., is.